# Passing a shared_ptr or unique_ptr to _beginthreadex

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I would like to know is this is possible. Create a shared_ptr or unique_ptr of TestClass type.

Then call _beginthreadex and pass it a static method of the class as the function to execute and the shared_ptr or unique_ptr created before as data. Like this:

```
shared_ptr<TestClass> p = make_shared<TestClass>(count, "test");
HANDLE hth1 = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, p->ThreadStart,p, 0, NULL);
```

I normally use this approach without smart pointers, I usually create a normal pointer of TestClass and pass a static method of the TestClass and the pointer itself as data, then inside the static method I cast it to (TestClass *) and run the member methods of the class etc, do the work and when the thread is done I delete the pointer. Something like this:

```
    TestClass * p = new TestClass(count, "test");
    HANDLE hth1 = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, p->ThreadStart,p, 0, NULL);
```

What I want to achieve is to make the smart pointer to delete the object automatically when the thread ends because the smart pointer would be out of scope.

When I do it the way I am describing it above the compiler shows this error:

"no suitable conversion function from "std::shared_ptr" to "void *" exists"

Comment: Did you consider using [standard thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) library? Then it would be perfectly possible

Comment: That is my next move if I cant do it like I tried first

Comment: This seems like a particularly silly use of `shared_ptr`. Oh, let's use this shared pointer. But it's shared and we don't want it to be shared. That's okay, we'll hack around to make it act like it's not shared. But then ... why do it at all? This would make perfect sense if you already had a `shared_ptr` or needed one for some reason (maybe the thread needs to extend the object's lifetime). But to create one just to undo its sole purpose ... crazy!

Comment: David, I don't think that you understood what I asked, but it is ok, txs anyways

Answer (score 2):

`_beginthreadex` looks like c function, and to achieve what you want, you need to invoke **copy constructor** (or **move** in case of `unique_ptr`) to transfer ownership, which is not possible in c.

You may consider using [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) class which plays nice with the rest of std suite.

Assuming you want to run:

```
void ThreadStart(std::shared_ptr<TestClass> p);
```

You can fire that by

```
void ThreadStart(std::shared_ptr<TestClass> p)
{
    cout << p->count << " " << p->name << endl;
}

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<TestClass> p = make_shared<TestClass>(33, "test");
    std::thread thr(ThreadStart, p);
    thr.join();
}
```

In case of `std::unique_ptr` you need to `std::move` it to the thread function, so it will be actually deleted at the thread's end:

```
void ThreadStart(std::unique_ptr<TestClass> p);
...
unique_ptr<TestClass> p = make_unique<TestClass>(33, "test");
std::thread thr(ThreadStart, std::move(p));
```

Comment: txs, but in this example the main thread outlives the spawned thread. in my case I want to create objects on the main thread, use them in another thread and getting rid of them at the end of the spawned thread. I want to use the fact that the smart_ptr will release the object when it goes out of scope, which can happen in several ways in the spawned thread. Wit the raw pointers you have to be careful not leak the memory if you don't do a delete.

Comment: When `std::thread` goes out of scope, it terminates the spawned thread by default, but you can call `thr.detatch()` instead of `thr.join()` so main thread will not wait for the termination of spawned thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`shared_ptr::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get) or [`unique_ptr::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) to get access to a pointer to the managed object.

```
shared_ptr<TestClass> p = make_shared<TestClass>(count, "test");
HANDLE hth1 = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, p->ThreadStart, p.get(), 0, NULL);
```

Comment: Is it safe to pass raw pointer to another thread? You are not passing ownership to it. What if shared_ptr deletes the owned object in the caller?

Comment: @RafalMielniczuk That would be a problem. The OP needs to ensure the smart pointers are kept alive until the thread completes.

Comment: @user3196371 Probably because the `shared_ptr` went out of scope, and deleted the managed object. You need to make sure that doesn't happen until your thread has completed execution. The exception you saw doesn't have anything to do with using `get` to access the raw pointer.